# Installing Tridion 2013 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 2

Tags: configuration

Windows Sever 2008 R2 Service Pack 2 is listed as a supported Operating System in SDLTridionWorld.com and SDLLiveContent.SDL.com but I keep getting the following error "The specified program requires a newer version of windows" when trying to install Tridion Content Manager using SDLTridion2013CM.exe.

Has anyone seen this error? Is it not possible to install Tridion 2013 on Windows Server 2008?

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to install on Windows 2008 R2 SP2, but not on Windows 2008 (no mater what SP it has). 2008 R2 and 2008 are different systems

Answer (score 3):

Here are the supported operating systems for SDL Tridion 2013 as per 2013 [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=SupportHistory_CM_OS.xml&docid=cmos_concept_55A2CDD6611B413693F6F9EC08CF4186&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoccmos_concept_55A2CDD6611B413693F6F9EC08CF4186&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US&action=search&query=oracle%2520client&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1377637190169&currentQuery=oracle%2520client&currentScope=)  [login required]

> Microsoft Windows 2008 **R2** SP1 (x64)
>
> Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (x64)